# How can I perform an add function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I need to perform a function! basically What the scenario is, there is two  elements used to increase and decrease a numerical value. The value is shown in a  element. I've shown the image where the elements are! How can I do this using JavaScript?

[image]

Update :

I wrote the following jQuery function for the element click event. But the result doesn't change when I click the element.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".amount-increase").click(function(
            var amount = parseInt($(".bill-item-amount span")text(),10);
            amount = amount + 1;
            $(".bill-item-amount span").text(amount);
        ));
    });
```

Here is the HTML element map.

```
 <div class="bill-item-description">
 <!-- Section for Item description and pricing -->
 <div class="bill-item-name">
 <p class="bill-item-name-left">Normal Cofee</p><p class="bill-item-name-right">170.00</p>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="bill-item-price">
 <span>170.00 USD</span>
 </div>
 <div class="bill-item-amount">
 <span>2</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bill-amount-selection">
 <!-- Section where the increment & decrement of item amount goes -->
 <a class="amount-increase" href="#"></a>
 <a class="amount-decrease" href="#"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: We need to see the actual JavaScript *code*, not just pictures of what the HTML renders

Comment: [I think there's a jQuery plugin for that](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I added the code I wrote for the function! Sorry I forgot to add the code! :( what I'm trying to do is, get the current element value by using the class name "bill-item-amount" and increase it by one and re post it as the element value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/QkgzB/

Take a look at this.. created for u...

```
              $(document).ready(function()
        {
        var x=2;
                $("#increase").click(function()
                {

                        x+=1;
                        $("#price").html(x);

                });

        });
```

Comment: Thanks man! you are a savior! but one little issue! I have multiple elements with the same class name! when I click on one increase button, all the elements gets updated with the current value! how to stop this?

Comment: Just give a unique id for each... and call them in jquery

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more to it than this, assuming you are getting the value from somewhere, or you can start it at 0 and add accordingly, but it's pretty easy with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hMfj/

HTML

```
<div id="box1">1</div>
<a href="#" id="increase1">Click</a>
```

javascript with jQuery

```
var x = 0; //<?php echo '$num' ?> or default setting or something
$("#increase1").click(function() {
    // This assumes you get value from database as number
    x+=1;
    $("#box1").html(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per ur image shown there are two side images which shows upwards and downwards..

http://jsfiddle.net/6hMfj/

Use one div(name :up) for upward to increase the value and use this code:

```
***var x = 0; 
$("#up").click(function() 
{    
    x+=1;
    $("#box1").html(x);
});***
```

Use another div(name :down) for downward and use this code

```
***var x = 0; 
$("#up").click(function() 
{    
    x-=1;
    $("#box1").html(x);
});***
```

Comment: Your answer gives what I want for some extent. but the sequence always start with 0 and increases with the click event! I've added the code I wrote with jQuery. can you help me with it! It doesn't show the value!

Comment: can u state me  << jQuery(".amount-increase") >> wat class this states..

Comment: it states the increase arrow of the html content! I've only written the code for the increment function.

Comment: Do u want change oly the value which is shown as 2 in pic or simultanously the USD DOLLAR ALSO.... pls refer me the id of both...

Comment: yes I only want to change the value of the 2, I dnt need to change the USD value! just the amount of 2. ".bill-item-amount" represents the number 2 element and ".amount-increase" represents the increase arrow element!

Comment: I'm getting the following error in my firebug.

missing formal parameter

var amount = parseInt($(".bill-item-amount span")text());

Comment: OK.. Fine... If u used that value in input box u can use it as .val().. or if u have used as div means u have to make it as jQuery(".bill-item-amount").text(); and replace with that jQuery(".bill-item-amount").text(amount);

Comment: I added the HTML code as well as the Jquery code. but still the error is there!

Comment: Just copy this code and make use of it::::

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var s1=170;
$("amt_in").click(function(){
  s1=s1+1;
  document.getElementById("price").value=s1;
  });
$("amt_de").click(function(){
  s1=s1-1;
  document.getElementById("price").value=s1;
  });

  });
```